# what is the minimum surface area shape required in order to contain a 1 meter line at all angles

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, surfaces, minimal-surfaces

been stuck on solving/proving the following puzzle:

You need to make a hole in the wall, so that a 1 meter line can pass it through the hole at all angels, find a shape with minimum surface area that would satisfy the above conditions ?

Comment: A cone maybe, not sure

Comment: Isn't this an unsolved problem?

Comment: @copper.hat a circle is not minimal, as a triangle with height length of 1 meter is less area and can accommodate for any angle the line is placed.

Comment: He didn't say area, he said surface.  Does that mean perimeter?

Comment: @MarsOneRover sorry if i wasn't clear, i meant the surface area (i.e. circle would be 2*pi*r^2) given r=1 it would be 2*pi

Comment: Isn't this the Kakeya needle problem then? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakeya_set

Comment: Doesn't the aforementioned Wikipedia article show that the minimum area (measure) is zero?

Comment: @copper.hat yes.

Comment: I don't understand the solution, What if the it wasn't a line, but a thin rod, would the shape be a deltoid curve?

Comment: See [curve of constant width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width). In particular, this is a [Reuleaux triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle).

Answer (score 2):

Take an equilateral triangle with sides of length $1$, and then use each vertex as the center of a  circular arc passing through the other two vertices:

[image]

This is at least a contender, with area $3\cdot\frac{\pi}{6}-2\cdot\frac{\sqrt3}{4}$, less than a circle of diameter $1$ or a quarter-circle of radius $1$, which are other convex shapes meeting the description. This shape may be the winner if you require a convex shape, but I have no ideas for proving it.